# javascript - pass a parameter through a submit form function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, submit

On clicking the retire user checkbox I am triggering the form submit for ("RetireUser", "Users")
My script is navigating to /Users/RetireUser but I need to pass the Id parameter.
Didn't have much luck with ajax
Thanks in advance for the help

```
@foreach (var item in UsersModel)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateRetired)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateAdded)</td>

                @using (Html.BeginForm("RetireUser", "Users", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", id="retire_user" }))
                {
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.RetireUser)</td>                       
                }
                <td><a href="@Url.Action("GetUserById", "Users", new { id = item.Id })">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        }


<script>
$('#item_RetireUser').click(function () {
    $('#retire_user').submit();
});
```

[the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrog7.png)
[the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81chq.png)

Comment: each click you are submit form to server?

Comment: yes, I want to be able to retire / re-instate the user

Comment: try to debug that value is getting there before put in the action

Comment: Also i suspect one thing, is this new { id = item.Id } you are doing in a string, will it do the object calling properly, i dn't know this .net,

Answer (score 0):

if it's a html why not give each  a id i.e  here 12 is user_id and with the help of jquery you can retrieve and send that id via ajax or normal url call.